# font anti-aliasing not working as expected

Tags: fonts, kde, arch-linux, xfce, anti-aliasing

it seems that my linux has problems with anti-aliasing fonts. As you can see in the picture the labels of the menu items are slightly pixelated.

[image: fonts in my system are pixelated].

On another system with exactly the same font settings the menu items look great. Any idea what's misconfigured?

Some details:
The problem appeared some days ago when I removed Gnome 3 and installed KDE. Now, the only installed desktop environment is xfce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jodell on [bbs.archlinux.org](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=128833) told me, just to remove **~/.fonts.conf**. Don't ask me, why I didn't tried that before.